# Is there any way to undo merging in blender?

Tags: modeling

I joined two objects in blender by selecting them and pushing CTRL + J. I was wondering whether there is a way to undo that and separate those two objects again. ( CTRL + Z didn't work. )

Comment: Technically: Alt+P > *Seperate by loose Parts*. However, Ctrl+Z should work in this case.

Comment: it's not alt P but P   ;)

Comment: Thank you guys, P > Separate by loose Parts worked.

Comment: Just be aware that P > Separate by Loose parts will produce more objects if your objects consist of multiple unconnected meshes. But ss @brockmann said, Ctrl+Z undo must work even for this action.

Comment: @JanKadeřábek Does it have anything to do with the fact that I rendered my picture once? Seems like Ctrl+z doesn't work after rendering.

Comment: @Naz I guess you have to use Ctrl + Z multiple times if you rendered after merging.